# Running an APK in ARC for chat application called Kik

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I have uploaded my APK which is a chat application named KIK on ARC. I logged on, but doesn't connect... Help please, my computer is connected to the internet via Wifi, I have used other emulators which work perfectly.

Have I done something wrong or there is something I haven't done right?

Comment: Please provide evidence that you are the developer of KIK.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried yet.

Comment: I highly doubt this guy is the developer of kik, this phrase alone("Help please, my computer is connected to the internet via wifi") makes that very unlikely.